# Rails - Get value by specifying the column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I get the value of one field from the a result? Here what I got so far:

This gives me the right value when I use row[8]:

```
<% @result.each{|row| %>
   <tr>
     <% row.each{|key| %>
       <td><%= key %></td>
     <% } %>
       <td><%= row[1] %></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```

However, I'm trying to get the value by column name. Using row["the_column_name"] doesn't seem to work as it returns "can't convert String into Integer". I think it's erroring because this is an array. How would I get the value by referencing the column name?

Comment: What is creating @result? Is it an array of hashes, an array of arrays, or something else? PS. Since it is an array, I'd suggest naming it @results, not @result. Or better @cars, @posts, etc -- What is the model/real world obj? -- A little self-documenting code.

Answer (score 0):

If your `@result` array is the result of an ActiveRecord search it will be an Array of objects, where the individual objects model the database table's row usually. You access an individual object's attributes, (i.e. row's fields) using the `.` accessor followed by the fieldname:

```
<% @result.each{|row| %>
   <tr>
       <td><%= row.fieldname1 %></td>
       <td><%= row.fieldname2 %></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```

Replace fieldname1 and fieldname2 with the names of the fields you want to display.

Comment: I get an error of "undefined method `fieldname1'". And of course I used the actual fieldname that's in my table.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the result is from doing a straight sql query using the execute method.

Comment: Take a look at my updated example code. I was on NyQuil when I wrote that before. I think the problem is you're trying to loop over the fields in your row, which isn't necessary. ActiveRecord will parse your returned results from the query into the attributes of the object. Each object is a row, each attribute of the object is a field returned by the query.

Comment: I still get the same error of "undefined method 'fieldname1'". What's odd is that row[1] works. But when using the fieldname, it errors out.